# Parse and Query XML code optimisation

Tags: php, xml

I have stored in a XML file some Travel packages, each package has a code( the codes are stored in an array = `$code`).

I am using the below code to pull the requested data from the XML based on the given code. At this time I have copy/paste the code for each given code, but I have lots more and I dont want to copy paste code over and over

How can I simplify the below code so I don't have to paste it for all code that I have?

```
 <?php
    $code = array("BAS12", "BAS12", "BAS13", "BAS14");

    $dom    = new DOMDocument();
    $xpath  = new DOMXPath($dom);
    $reader = new XMLReader();
    $reader->open("file.xml");

    while ($reader->read()) {
        if ($reader->nodeType == XMLReader::ELEMENT && $reader->name == 'Hotel') {
            $node = $dom->importNode($reader->expand(), true);
            $dom->appendChild($node);
            $nume1 = $xpath->evaluate('string(self::Hotel[HotelCode = "'.$code[0].'"]/HotelName)', $node);
            $tara1 = $xpath->evaluate('string(self::Hotel[HotelCode = "'.$code[0].'"]/Country)', $node);
            $oras1 = $xpath->evaluate('string(self::Hotel[HotelCode = "'.$code[0].'"]/City)', $node);
            $adresa1 = $xpath->evaluate('string(self::Hotel[HotelCode = "'.$code[0].'"]/Adress)', $node);
            $stele1 = $xpath->evaluate('string(self::Hotel[HotelCode = "'.$code[0].'"]/Stars)', $node);
            $masa1 = $xpath->evaluate('string(self::Hotel[HotelCode = "'.$code[0].'"]/TipMasa)', $node);
            $camera1 = $xpath->evaluate('string(self::Hotel[HotelCode = "'.$code[0].'"]/TipCamera)', $node);
            $pret1 = $xpath->evaluate('string(self::Hotel[HotelCode = "'.$code[0].'"]/Pret)', $node);
            $descriere1 = $xpath->evaluate('string(self::Hotel[HotelCode = "'.$code[0].'"]/Descriere)', $node);
            $persoane1 = $xpath->evaluate('string(self::Hotel[HotelCode = "'.$code[0].'"]/Persoane)', $node);
            $img1 = $xpath->evaluate('string(self::Hotel[HotelCode = "'.$code[0].'"]/Imagine1)', $node);
              $dom->removeChild($node);
            if ($nume1) {
                 break; }
            if ($tara1) {
                 break; }            
            if ($oras1) {
                 break; }
             if ($adresa1) {
                 break; }   
                  if ($stele1) {
                 break; }
                  if ($camera1) {
                 break; }   
                  if ($masa1) {
                 break; }   
                  if ($pret1) {
                 break; }       
                  if ($persoane1) {
                 break; }   
                   if ($img1) {
                 break; }

        }
    }
    ?>
```

Answer (score 1):

Why don't you read the code into a variable and check if it is in the array of codes? After that fill up an array with the results.

Nearly every time you have a variable with a counter in the name, you should use arrays.

Another optimization is using XMLReader::next() to go directly to the next sibling without reading the child nodes.

You don't need to append the imported node, you need to provide it as a context in the `DOMXpath::evaluate()` calls anyway.

```
$codes = ["BAS11", "BAS12", "BAS13", "BAS14"];
$hotels = [];

$dom = new DOMDocument();
$xpath = new DOMXPath($dom);

$reader = new XMLReader();
$reader->open($filename);

// look for the first Hotel element (include descendants)
while ($reader->read() && $reader->localName !== 'Hotel') {
  continue;
}

// while you have an Hotel element
while ($reader->localName === 'Hotel') {
  // no need to append the node to the document, just import it
  $node = $dom->importNode($reader->expand(), true);
  // read the HotelCode
  $code = $xpath->evaluate('normalize-space(./HotelCode)', $node);
  // if it is in the list
  if (in_array($code, $codes)) {
    // read the values
    $hotels[$code] = [
      'name' => $xpath->evaluate('string(./HotelName)', $node),
      'country' => $xpath->evaluate('string(./Country)', $node),
      //...
    ];
  }
  // move directly to the next Hotel sibling
  $reader->next('Hotel');  
}

var_dump($hotels);
```